Why does the command $git --version produce an error?
I recently installed and setup git on my computer (windows 8.1) to learn basic use with it in vs code with Python. However, when I enter the command $git --version in the terminal window to check the git version (which was according to the tutorial I've been learning from), I get the following error:
At line:1 char:8
+ $git --version
+        ~~~~~~~
Unexpected token 'version' in expression or statement.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken

Does anyone know how to solve this problem or what I'm doing wrong?
I've tried entering git --version in the terminal instead (without the $), and it says the following:
git: The term 'git' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1 
+ git --version
+ ~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (git:string) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

I've also tried entering $git version (without the --) and it produced the same result as the first error. I was expecting it display the git version in the terminal window.

$ is a prompt character. You're not supposed to type it; what you should type is just git --version. (On traditionally UNIXy systems, the prompt for non-root users ends in $, so the character is used in documentation as a "type at your prompt" sigil).

As for the "not recognized as the name of a cmdlet" error -- check and fix your PATH so it includes the location that git.exe is installed at. That's the same for all software, not just git (and not just development tools in general), so it's not really a software-development-specific problem, and so not particularly on-topic for Stack Overflow.

I'd argue that this is largely duplicative of error: git is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet and/or error: git is not recognized as an internal or external command (and that the parts that aren't duplicative aren't on-topic and belong on Super User rather than Stack Overflow at all).

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=The+term+%27git%27+is+not+recognized+as+the+name+of+a+cmdlet%2C+function%2C+script

This wasn’t “caused by a typo” since OP honestly thought that $ was part of the command.

$ isn't part of the command, it's just a common prompt in *nix shells. When you run it like this, $git is interpreted as an environment variable, which is probably empty, so you end up running --version.
In short - lose the $. The command you're trying to run is git --version.
If git isn't recognized as command, it means the directory where that executable is installed isn't in your $PATH variable.
